# Difference between asynchronous sockets and NIO and using them together?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, nio

I am doing a project where they recommend us to use NIO instead of sockets: I understand that in NIO many clients can register with a selector, and that selector assigns a worker when a client has data, but with sockets once registered clients keep the server blocked.

But what are asynchronous sockets then? I figured if I am using NIO server then I should also use NIO client right? But I saw lots of code they use asynchronous sockets on the client side, but wont sockets be blocking? If so where are they blocking and how is it possible to use 2 technologies on each end?

**Note:** I would like it if someone explained or give some good references,but I have already read a LOT and I am so confused, so I would prefer an explanation as to their differences and what would happen if I had a asynchrnous client socket and NIO server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's explain what is the difference between NIO and Async operations and websockets.

**None Blocking -** - means the server / client / app doesn't block. It's usually refers only to the process in which it is running (although it might effect the other side, like websockets do). This could be implemented in many various ways, using just threads in a synchronous manner, using async operations (single or multi-threaded, single threaded node.js style, etc.

**Async -** is one implementation for a none blocking way to handle operations.

**Java NIO** - a Java implementation for a none-blocking server -

> Java NIO (New IO) is an alternative IO API for Java (from Java 1.4),
>   meaning alternative to the standard Java IO and Java Networking API's.
>   Java NIO offers a different way of working with IO than the standard
>   IO API's.
>   http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html

**WebSockets -** an implementation for using sockets in JavaScript projects, there are a vary of ways the sockets can work, and a selection of libraries that implement them..The idea is to provide a socket based interface for JS apps.

Having explain all of that let's look at what you're asking.

The means Java.NIO is only on the server, and doesn't care about the client side at all! I suspect you might need to either use a JAVA.NIO client, or find a way to have an implementation that supports websockets. How the client connects and manages it's side is up to the client, it might be an applet or js script, the server just expects a client connect to follow a certain protocol or communicate in a certain way. The client can be blocking or none-blocking, the server wouldn't care about that at all. from a brief look, it seems that the server looks for client side connection using winsocket like connections (which is different to websockets protocol). You should look for a JAVA NIO that support WebSockets, or maybe implement your own selector etc. Here is how to build a Java Server with WebSockets - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Fi4vz6oUio

WebSockets clients can use a variety of ways to communicate (pooling, async and many others, and tend to be non-blocking) there are various libraries out there, such as socket.io or here is a list of various implementations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations. You could use socket.io on the client side and find a good implementation for a server side websocket, then use it with you NIO Java Server..

Either way the blocking can happen either on a client / server or both. It really depends how you implement each, but either way you must choose compatible technologies, and there is not right or wrong answer here. But if you're running javascript, you prob would need to use websockets, or some form of it  :)

I hope this helps.

Comment: THank you for your answer, I am using plain java, I have the doubt as to how it would function if I used asynchronous socket client with nio server? Like client would connect to server,since its a socket would it block? if yes when? the server side would not be blocked because it is using selectors, but then what kind of resources does the client block? I am confused about that.

Comment: Please read what I wrote again. Blocking in the client and blocking on the server are two separate things. A Socket can block an a socket can not block, it depends on the server, from looking at NIO, you can have it blocking or none blocking. Async is none-blocking always! Why would the client block if you're using Async?

Comment: No. Asynchronous I/O is *completely different* from non-blocking I/O, not another way to implement it'. It is in fact blocking I/O carried out on a secret thread, possibly an operating system thread, with a rendezvous or callback executed when the operation completes.

Comment: You need to understand that each side is independent of the other. having a none-blocking server, doesn't mean the client is block or is none blocking and vice versa..

Comment: @EJP you are incorrect. Async is either single or multi-threaded ,and it is one way to handle none-blocking io.

Comment: It is one way to handle *blocking* I/O. That's why there is a `Future` for it in Java. Because it *has* a future. Non-blocking I/O has no future. It's either finished or it wants to block to complete.

Comment: @EJP Non-blocking has no future? Non-Blocking is just that, non-blocking. This has nothing to do with futures etc. Async is just a way to handle non-blocking buddy, your answer is very misleading and confusing.. Async is not blocking io! as it doesn't block...

Comment: @LoveMeow do my first answers help you ?

Comment: They do! I was confused about this blocking thing,thanks!

Comment: @DoryZidon Blocking has no `Future`. Do read what I actually wrote. Don't indulge in straw-man arguments.

Answer (score -1):

- Blocking: the method blocks until the operation is complete or an error occurs
- Non-blocking: the method never blocks: it either completes immediately or reports an error saying it would block if you had carried it out in blocking mode
- Asynchronous: the method returns immediately and the operation continues in the background, with a rendezvous or callback executed when it completes.

Comment: Async is a subset of none-blocking, you're just describing how it works, but it's not a separate category mate.

Comment: You're just re-affirming what I said.. async is non-blocking..is a subset of non-blocking..read your comment before..you said it's blocking....

Comment: @DoryZidonN No, I am contradicting what you said. There are three distinct categories.